# What is Structure of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA?

Tags: portable-executable, import-table

Can anyone explain the structure of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA?

I just know it has 4 elements, but I want the explanation of these elements.

Comment: You might find https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/13385 useful. It has a structure with named members for this PE section. Also have you search around? Did https://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/pe-tut6.html not answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I saw that, but it didn't explain it. 
The first link is ok. thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMAGE_THUNK_DATA is defined like so:

```cpp
typedef struct _IMAGE_THUNK_DATA {
    union {
        uint32_t* Function;             // address of imported function
        uint32_t  Ordinal;              // ordinal value of function
        PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME AddressOfData;        // RVA of imported name
        DWORD ForwarderStringl              // RVA to forwarder string
    } u1;
} IMAGE_THUNK_DATA, *PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA;
```

The comments should explain it well enough